# Difference between date in JavaScript: How many hours between new Date() and new Date(unix_time_stamp)

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have the following coming response from the database:

```
{
  "createdAt": "1634413505432"
}
```

I want to convert this `timestamp` to something like `1 hour ago`, `7 sec ago`, `2 weeks ago` based on the current date (`new Date()`). So I've tried to get the difference between the two dates but seems not working. maybe i'm doing it wrong.

```js
Date.now() - 1634414179357 # i get 370517

new Date(370517 * 1000).getHours() # i get 8 which is wrong
```

Can someone show me how to do this.

Comment: new Date(370517 * 1000) will initialize Date object with a timestamp - depends on the local time zome. In order to find diff you can use moment.js or some lib, or calc like diffTs = (Date.now() - 1634414179357); hours = diffTs/60/60/1000

Comment: Use *getUTCHours*, but that's only good for up to 24 hours. Generally, use `(Date.now() - 1634413505432) / 3.6e6` which gives about 2 at the moment.

Comment: BTW, the time value appears to be milliseconds: `new Date(1634413505432).toISOString()` gives "2021-10-16T19:45:05.432Z". The value 370517 is only about 6 minutes.

Comment: @RobG thanks so much it did work the way i wanted.